# Root Locus for k=0

Tags: control-system

I’m learning about the root locus and I see that the root locus varies the gain starting from 0 and then monitors the closed loop poles positions in the s-domain.

Consider the following system
[image]

How can the root locus start from a gain of 0? The system would be invalid?

Comment: why would it be invalid?

Comment: @sarthak K cannot be equal to 0, that would mean the eq 1 which is invalid and hence the roots do not exist.

Comment: From a block level perspective, if k = 0, the feedforward TF is 0 - how would you find the poles of that system then?

Comment: The roots can also be complex, can't they? Although the gain K which is varied is usually in the feedback path, I think.

Comment: @sarthak Oh really? I didn't realise the root locus usually uses the feedback gain to vary. In that case, when the gain is 0, the root locus poles would just be the open loop poles right?

Comment: Yes you are right!

Comment: Great. Thank you!